# Hibernate, test if a collection is fully loaded

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, lazy-loading

Is there a way to test if a collection is already initialized? `try-catch` only?

I have a function work with a lazy collection, and I need to load it only if is not already loaded.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`Hibernate.initialize(collection)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize%28java.lang.Object%29) This will initialize the collection if it is not yet.

(There is another method - `Hibernate.isInitialized(collection)`, but since you want to actually load the collection, `initialize(..)` is the way to go - it makes the same check before proceeding to initialization)

Comment: Thank you. Did you mean Hibernate.isInitialized(collection)?

Comment: That's just exactly what the OP is looking for. +1

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks.